# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.inn.wireless.data.Users

Tags: java, android, error-handling

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.inn.wireless.data.Users
            at com.inn.activity.parser.INITParser.parseLoginResponse(INITParser.java:87)
            at com.inn.activity.parser.INITParser.parseLoggedInUserResponse(INITParser.java:69)
            at com.inn.activity.net.RequestHandler.sendLoginRequest(RequestHandler.java:267)
            at com.inn.activity.LoginActivity$CheckLoginAsyn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:227)
            at com.inn.activity.LoginActivity$CheckLoginAsyn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:207)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

**Users** class add in my project
So what is problem is there.

I have error in this line
    **Users user = new Gson().fromJson(json, Users.class);**

this error occur if i add **compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'** this dependency

i use AndroidStudio in ubuntu 14

Comment: what does your project/file structure look like?

Comment: Your class name is User.java or Users.java?

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError` in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime. There could be multiple reason:

- class not present in classpath
- Any start-up script is overriding classpath environment variable
- `NoClassDefFoundError` due to the failure of static initialization is quite common

Check [this blog](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) to get some more info. In your case JVM is not able to find `Users.class` at runtime.

Please, share your project structure to improve this answer.

Comment: So, how to set classpath in Ubuntu 14   and  what is a solution of these 3 reason